# "Service firestore not available" with code that worked a few days ago

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I’m using the `firebase 9.18.0` npm package in a React web app and a few days ago all Firestore requests started failing with `“Error: Service firestore is not available”`.  My code has not changed since this last worked smoothly (and to be sure I rolled back to the first commit of this code to eliminate that possibility).

Other questions similar to this one have not proved useful (this was coded on and is already using the latest version of Firebase).

My Firebase connection still works for the Auth service, and I am able to log in and log out without trouble.

Firebase Status does not report any service problems and a ticket I filed with Google 2 days ago remains unanswered.  When I first built this Firestore fetch code, I had no problems getting it to work.  I’ve verified via Firestore Console that my collections are still there.

The basic flow is:

```
import { getFirestore, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
const fbApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  // using this same object to getAuth(fbApp) works fine
const firestore = getFirestore(fbApp);  // throws "Error: Service firestore is not available"
```

I also tried fetching via the library `@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments 0.0.6` instead of `firebase 9.18.0` and it produces the same error.  How can one get through to Google about what appears to be a systems issue?  Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Edit to add more details:

I don't believe the config is the issue, because the initialization permits other Firebase services to work, such as Auth:

```
import { getFirestore, getAuth, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
const fbApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  
const auth = getAuth(fbApp); // works fine, can log users in, etc.
const firestore = getFirestore(fbApp);  // throws "Error: Service firestore is not available"
```

This is the config referred to in the code above, copied directly from Firebase console:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AI9ugIOBOupGHgTF345535OllGghyoGLjhILjhG76575WIc",
  authDomain: "flashlang-2.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "flashlang-2",
  storageBucket: "flashlang-2.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "762856867559",
  appId: "1:762856867559:web:72c7d5e56dfd55d098c442",
  measurementId: "G-0FZLD3MDEB",
};
```

[image: Firestore db snapshot]

Comment: Are you sure that you are importing `initializeApp` from `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";` and also have you deleted the the web app you registered in the firebase project console ?

Comment: @RohitKharche  Yes, I am calling `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"`.  As mentioned, I am able to use the same initialized app (fbApp in the code above) to authenticate users, and I can go to the Firebase dashboard and see users, collections, etc.

Comment: I also double-checked that the firebaseConfig keys in the console have not changed and match what I'm using to initialize the app.

Comment: I also tried temporarily changing Firestore access rules to permit read/write to every collection by any user, and that did not fix anything.

Comment: If possible can you edit the question and include the entire firebase sdk initialization without revealing your credentials and a snapshot of your firestore db ?

Comment: I added the additional details on to the end of the original question

Comment: I just looked in to an old app that I haven't used for sometime. It no longer works and has this same issue. Something must have changed with Firestore. But the strange thing is that I can find no reference to it, it's as if the only people with problems with it are you and me. It does work if I change my imports from "firebase/firestore" to "firebase/firestore/lite"

Comment: Checked this today and it's working again. I can only assume there was some issue with firebase. I could access the data via the console and if I used firebase/firestore/lite, not the usual firebase/firestore. This is not a good situation for firebase to be in.